# sending dynamic data from one route to other

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to send data from students/my-students route to students/student-profile/:id 
both belong to different module which is child module of student-post-login module.

**In my-students.html**

```
<div *ngFor="student of students">
<a (click)="goToStudentProfile(student)"> student name </a>
</div>
```

**my-students.ts**

goToStudentProfile(student)
{

```
  let studentData = { "firstName": student.firstname,
    "phone": student.phone,
    "email": student.email,
    "birthdate": student.birth_date
    }

  this.studentsService.studentBasicInfo = []
  this.studentsService.studentBasicInfo.push(studentData );
this.router.navigate(['students/student-profile/student.student_id'])

}
```

In **studentsService** I have studentBasicInfo public field declared as

```
studentBasicInfo = [];
```

**student-profile component:**

```
ngOnInit()
{
 console.log("studentBasicInfo", this.studentsService.studentBasicInfo) 
}

//Output: studentBasicInfo  undefined
```

I tried this with behaviorSubject as well but may be both components are from different module so that is also not working.

Any ideas that how I can fix this?

**UPDATE**
**I have also tried:**

my-students.component.ts

```
this.studentsService.setData(studentsData)
```

service:

```
studentData = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null)
studentData$ = this.studentData.asObservable();
setData(data)
{
    this.studentData.next(data)
}
```

student-profile.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){

this.studentService.studentData$.subscribe(

data=>
{
  console.log("subscribed",data)
})
}

//Output subscribed
```

Explained my scenario:
[stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8etio?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
But unfortunately it is not working due to dependency issue.

**UPDATE:**
This part of answer from **Aniket avhad** solved my problem:

> In order two share a service between multiple components, you should
>   provide the service at a level higher and not add the service to the
>   providers of both components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is your solution, your rxjs **BehaviorSubject** will also worked, only you have to do that is add service where you initialize rxjs studentData 
and add that service into main module **provider**.

> In order two share a service between multiple components, you should
>   provide the service at a level higher and not add the service to the
>   providers of both components.

Now check my solution here,

first create `common.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {

  studentData = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null)
  studentData$ = this.studentData.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

}
```

and in `app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private router: Router, private commonService: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  students = [
    { id: 1, name: 'student1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'student4' },
    { id: 3, name: 'student3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'student2' }

  ];

  goToStudentProfile(student) {
    let studentData = {
      "firstName": student.name,
      "id": student.id,
    }

    this.commonService.studentData.next(studentData);
    this.router.navigate([`student/${student.id}`]);
  }
}
```

and in `child.component` i.e. your student

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.commonService.studentData$.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbjvfy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fstudent%2Fstudent.component.ts) demo

Comment: thanks alot. But not working in my scenario. I have created a https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8etio?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts demo to explain structure of my modules.

Comment: also I am using angular 5.

Comment: Ok as you are using angular 5 so, create one shared module and add this service into that module providers and import shared module into your 'app.component.ts' and also in your lazy module i.e. child module

Comment: Thanks Aniket avhad, one change made it work. I removed service from child components. I can't thankyou enough. Would never be able to find this out.

Comment: If you get time, can you tell me why including service in sub modules was causing issue? This will help me in future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you output data only when component is initializing. Try to use RxJS to subscribe on data changing.

```
export class studentsService {
  dataUpdated:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  setData(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.dataUpdated.emit(this.data);
  }
}
```

And your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._studentsService.dataUpdated.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. Which lifecycle hook do you suggest. As I stated I even tried using rxjs subject but when I subscribe to subject in student-profile I get no data where as I get data on subscription in my-students component.

Comment: I guess life-cycle hooks won't help in this case, because you don't have any data-bound properties.
I would use EventEmitter in your service and then subscribe on this event to be notified when data is changed.

Comment: I have also tried that method. Please check I have updated my post.
observable method is also not working. Can you help further?

Comment: Thanks Alexander but this is also not working. Not reaching in subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can also trying using RXJS BehaviorSubject.

**Service:**

```
export class studentsService {
  private transferData = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  public transferData$ = this.transferData.asObservable();

  setData(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.transferData.next(this.data);
  }
}

**In your Component**

 ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
    this._studentsService.transferData$.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
    }, 500);
  }
```

Comment: Tried this. nothing prints in console not even static message.

Comment: No output for subscription even after adding setTimeout.
thanks for help though

Comment: Where as If I subscribe in my-students component then data prints.

Comment: Then we need to use BehaviorSubject. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this.

```
<div *ngFor="student of students">
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="btn btn-secondary" routerLink="/students/student-profile/{{student.id}}"> Update User</button>
</div>
```

and then use ActivatedRoute to get your id on your destination module.

```
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router'; 

    constructor( route: ActivatedRoute) {
        var userId = route.snapshot.params['id'];
       }
```

Comment: masera ngelekanyo I need a json Data and not just ':id' so I need to use some common service. Thanks for help though! :)